# Dynamic form in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have created a dynamic form using vbscript. It displays fine but when I click on submit button it does not post the page back... Can anyone help me? Code I have written is:

```
<form method="post" action="home.asp">
    <%if session("id")="" then
        response.write("<div id=logindiv>Login ID: <input type=text ID=loginID name=loginID /><br/><br/>Password: <input type=password ID=password name = password/><br/><br/><a href=register.asp/>Sign Up</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=submit id=loginbtn name=loginbtn value=Login /></div>")
    else
        response.write("already logged in")
    end if%>
</form>
```

The resulting html is this:

```
<form method="post" action="home.asp">
    <div id=logindiv>Login ID: <input type=text ID=loginID name=loginID /><br/><br/>Password: <input type=password ID=password name = password/><br/><br/><a href=register.asp/>Sign Up</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=submit id=loginbtn name=loginbtn value=Login /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This has ZERO to with with ASP sine 100% of it happens on the client. Please show the resulting HTML, not your ASP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra / in your anchor tag:

```
<a href=register.asp/>
```

Maybe unrelated, but if it's closing the element, the  after "Sign Up" could be screwing up the .

Comment: I had an extra character! Not with register.asp but with password name... Oh Man this asp is killing me...

Comment: Thank you very much for bringing this up :)

Comment: Always a good idea to quote attribute values in HTML.  I believe in an ASP string this is done with a double double-quote i.e. ""